# make todo and store in localstorage but getting this error fetchdata.map is not a function at App (App.js:27:1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';


export default function App() {

  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState();
  const [fetchdata, setFetchData] = useState([])
  const addHandler = () => {
    setState((data) => {
      return [...data, inputData];
    });

    localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state));
    setInputData('');
  };
  setFetchData(localStorage.getItem('state'))
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => setInputData(e.target.value)}
        value={inputData || ''}
        placeholder="add items"
      />
      <button onClick={addHandler}>Add</button>
      {fetchdata?.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div style={{ color: `#+${color}` }}>
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          </div>
        );
      }) || []}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**This is the code I have tried also need dynamic colors for lists. Any help is appreciated with big thanks**

even the key I have given unique but it says unique key required

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a default value to your fetchData:

```
const [fetchdata, setFetchData] = useState(localStorage.getItem('state') ?? []);
```

and please don't begin to use useless useEffect like every begginer are doing, further documentation [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) !

Answer (score 0):

try:

- remove

```
setFetchData(localStorage.getItem('state'))
```

- replace

```
const initData = () => {
 try {
   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'));
 } catch (e) {
   return [];
 }
}
const [fetchdata, setFetchData] = useState(initData())
```